# Google Captcha without image verfication

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I want to integrate google re-captcha without image verification.how can i do this??

[image]

Comment: Change Captcha system

Comment: which captcha system @vincent

Comment: But they have [cats](http://imgur.com/XcVhADZ), why would you not want them?

Comment: No need this verification i want check robot ticks only @Rizier123

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the first few times you use a reCaptcha, you won't see the pictures. But the more you use it, the harder it gets.

Put the reCaptcha at the end in your website, or put it in comments untill you are ready to test/launch the website.